# Instagram authentication page layout not responsive in Android WebView Dialog box

Tags: android, authentication, layout, webview, instagram

In my Android app I'm using a WebView Dialog box to allow the user to authenticate their Instagram account within my app. This process follows the outlined OAuth2.0 protocol as explained at https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/.

My WebView looks like this: 
[image]

How can I show the entirety of the authentication page within the WebView Dialog?

Comment: doesn't instagram have an sdk, like facebook's sdk that does this for you??

Comment: That page is "owned" by Instagram and they show it however they want (unfortunately). You can check `EyeEm` app, it also have Instagram integration and it also looks crap, because that's what Instagram provides.